# MySQL query with php contact form 7

Tags: mysql, wordpress, looker-studio, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 in my WordPress site for registration and trying to display the registration info in google data studio.

The field of `form_value` is like this:

`a:9:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:9:"your-name";s:19:"John";s:10:"your-email";s:28:"john@gmail.com";s:9:"tel-phone";s:8:"20000000";s:15:"your-schoolname";s:2:"LA";s:10:"menu-which";a:1:{i:0;s:6:"Primary";}s:16:"text-schoolother";s:0:"";s:10:"menu-where";a:1:{i:0;s:3:"eDM";}s:10:"text-other";s:0:"";}`

I hope to extract the data in the string like: John; john@gmail.com; 20000000; Primary etc.
I have try two way to work on this, the db should be 5.7 in mysql

1. Custom query, but i am not sure how to do it, i try to queryjson_extract() but it seem an invalid value because of the 'a:9:' in the beginning of the data ...
2. Filter it on google data studio, i try left() but the string of every result is not the same.

How can I perform it?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I finish in substring_index

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(form_value,'";',4),':"',-1) AS Name,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(form_value,'";',6),':"',-1) AS Email,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(form_value,'";',8),':"',-1) AS Phone
...
```